# elasticsearch array query containing json data

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I want to query on complex data nested in arrays in elasticsearch. My data looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Alice and Bob",
    "attribs": [
        {
            "attrib-name": "city",
            "attrib-value": "London"
        },
        {
            "attrib-name": "interest",
            "attrib-value": "Shopping"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to query the data stored in elasticsearch and ask for all documents with:

```
"attrib-value": "London"
```

Or more advanced for documents with:

```
"attrib-name": "city"
"attrib-value": "Hong-Kong"
```

I know that there other ways to store the data, i.e. not using arrays with `"attrib-name"` and `"attrib-value"` but in this case it's given and I'm looking for ways on how to query on the existing model.

Comment: If you want to query `"attrib-name": "city"
"attrib-value": "Hong-Kong"` you will need `nested` fields. Regular array of objects will not work. It will match, also, `"attrib-name": "interest" "attrib-value": "Hong-Kong"`.

Comment: Why you need `nested` fields: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html